# Facebook Login Dialog Loop

Tags: facebook, authentication, dialog, facebook-iframe

How do i retrieve the code error from Facebook login dialog?

I'm using the PHP SDK for login dialog and permissions in my application.

When a user don't allow the application, the app may repeatedly redirecting people to the Login Dialog after they decline permission requests.

The app is running on iframe, so I have nothing in my GET variable.

Here's the code :

```php
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
 $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
 $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
 . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&scope=email,publish_stream,publish_actions&state=" . $_SESSION['state'];

 echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}
```